# Php files are exposed in Palapa webserver (Lighttpd server) when using CAPS in URL file extension

Tags: php, android, file, server, lighttpd

**Php** files are **exposed**, when someone use **CAPS in URL file extension**, when using **Palapa Web Server**:

**For example:**

**a)** If we type:

```
www.domain.com/index.php
```

php runs well

**b)** If we type:

```
www.domain.com/index.PHP
```

or one of these in the extension:
**P**hp || p**H**p || ph**P** || **PH**p || p**HP** || **P**h**P** || **PHP**

the webserver **do not execute php code** 
but instead **sends the** php **file** to the client as file, 
**so everyone can download it**, and the **code is exposed**.

This is an important security issue in some cases.

Is there any way to fix it?
(for example convert the extension to lowercase)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it just **adding this line** in the **Lighttpd configuration settings**

```
server.force-lowercase-filenames = "enable"
```